# `freopen` and checking if file is writable

Tags: c++

I have a program where a user has the option to save output to a file. To achieve this, I'm using `freopen`.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){   
    if(argc == 1 || argc > 3){
        cerr << "Please specify a SINGLE .txt file to generate word chains from." << endl << "OPTIONAL: specify a log file to store program output. Recommended when processing very large text files." << endl;
        cerr << "Usage: ./PeekClientRMS /path/to/file.txt /path/to/logfile.txt" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    if(argc == 3){ 
        cout << "Saving output to file " << argv[2] << "."; 
        freopen(argv[2],"w",stdout); 
    }


        // do some stuff here and generate output


    if(argc == 3){ 
        fclose(stdout); 
    }

}
```

However, if I specify a log file such as `/this/clearly/isnt/writable.txt` it executes without throwing an error. Is there something like `ifstream`'s `fail()` method that I could use to catch it?

Comment: If `freopen` fails, it returns `NULL` and may set `errno`.  Note that before it attempts to open the new file it closes the old file, so if the open fails, you can't use the `FILE*` anymore (`stdout`, in this case) because it's been closed.

Comment: freopen(3) is for use in **C**, mixing C++ and C I/O is shouting for trouble.

Comment: try using `#include <fstream>` library

Comment: It seems like freopen is not the ideal solution for what I am trying to do.